# To-do list application: Why does my code prevent me from deleting the most recently added list element?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, nodelist, queryselector

I'm trying to create a to-do list application. I'm using JS to dynamically create list elements on the web page when a user clicks on the submit button along with their user input.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
const inputTXT = document.querySelector('.inputText');          //input element
const submitBUTT = document.querySelector('.submitButton');     //button element
const listITEMS = document.querySelector('.items');             //list element

function createListElement(inputString){

    const newListItem = document.createElement("li");
    const newEditButton = document.createElement("button");
    const newDeleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    const listText = document.createTextNode(inputString);
    newListItem.appendChild(listText);
    const editText = document.createTextNode("Edit");
    newEditButton.appendChild(editText);
    const deleteText = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    newDeleteButton.appendChild(deleteText);

    newListItem.appendChild(newEditButton);
    newListItem.appendChild(newDeleteButton);

    //assign class to each list element for line below:
    newDeleteButton.className = "deleteCLASS";
    newEditButton.className = "editCLASS";

    //delete function:
    var deleteButtonArray = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteCLASS");   

    for(var i=0; i < deleteButtonArray.length ; ++i){
        deleteButtonArray[i].onclick = function(){
            this.parentNode.remove();
        }
    }
    
    return newListItem;
}




function addTask(){
    listITEMS.classList.remove('hidden');
    const ITEM = createListElement(inputTXT.value);
    document.getElementsByClassName("items")[0].appendChild(ITEM);
    inputTXT.value = '';    //Resets user input string
}



submitBUTT.addEventListener("click", addTask);
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main-header{
    background: #e7e7e7;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.inputText{
    margin-top: 20px;

}

h1{
    font-size: 35px;
}

ul{
    list-style: square;
    margin-left: 275px;
}

.hidden{
    display: none;
}

.itemLIST{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.editBUTT{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.deleteBUTT{
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title> "To-do List" </title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "container">



        
            <div class = "main-header">

                <h1>My To-do List</h1>

                <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Item"  class= "inputText" required> 

                <button class = "submitButton">Submit</button>

            </div>

            <ul class ="items hidden">
        
            </ul>
   

        

        </div>
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works for the most parts, but I cannot delete the last list element for some reason.

The only debugging I've done to figure out what is happening is print out the "deleteButtonArray" variable, which uses the keyword "querySelectorAll". From this, I found out that when the user hits the submit button, an empty NodeList printed. When the user hits the submit button a second time, only then do we get a NodeList with 1 element. When the user hits the submit button a third time, we get a NodeList with 2 elements.

It looked like the problem had something to do with querySelectorAll not properly updating in time when the user hits the submit button. I replaced it with getElementsByClassName, and still the same issue.

Now, I think the problem has something to do with the way I'm trying to implement the delete function within the createListElement function.

The way I think my code works:
Every time a user hits the submit button, a list element is created along with an array (actually a NodeList) that contains all the list elements present so far. This means that if I delete list elements, the array will update with the correct number of list elements.

And, it does update correctly, for the most parts. I just don't know why the array is empty when we first create an element. Shouldn't querySelectorAll or getElementsByClassName return a non-empty NodeList when the user first hits the submit button?

Comment: Can you update your code such that it represents a [mre]? Your code is currently broken because you haven't added the requisite HTML to your snippet. Your core question "*I just don't know why the array is empty when we first create an element.*" isn't possibly answerable without seeing the associated HTML.

Comment: You're adding a bunch of event listeners on the delete buttons **every time you add a new list element**. Don't do that. Instead, just add an event listener on `newDeleteButton` and call `newListItem.remove()`. If you've already got references to elements, there is absolutely no need to query the document for them

Comment: The reason your `querySelectorAll(".deleteCLASS")` doesn't return the latest button is because at that stage, it hasn't been added to the document because `newListItem` hasn't been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so here's a solution I've tried and tested it, and it seems to be working.

I removed the delete item portion out of the createListElement function, made it its own function, and added an event listener to each delete button that's created, so it will run the now separate delete function when clicked.

No changes were made to the HTML or the CSS.

```
const inputTXT = document.querySelector('.inputText');          //input element
const submitBUTT = document.querySelector('.submitButton');     //button element
const listITEMS = document.querySelector('.items');             //list element

function createListElement(inputString){

    const newListItem = document.createElement("li");
    const newEditButton = document.createElement("button");
    const newDeleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    const listText = document.createTextNode(inputString);
    newListItem.appendChild(listText);
    const editText = document.createTextNode("Edit");
    newEditButton.appendChild(editText);
    const deleteText = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    newDeleteButton.appendChild(deleteText);

    newListItem.appendChild(newEditButton);
    newListItem.appendChild(newDeleteButton);
  
//Here is the new addEventListener
    newDeleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteStuff);


    //assign class to each list element for line below:
    newDeleteButton.className = "deleteCLASS";
    newEditButton.className = "editCLASS";
    
    return newListItem;
}

//Here is the new delete function. The onclick function that was there before has been removed because, in this case, it's not needed.
function deleteStuff() {
   //delete function:
    var deleteButtonArray = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteCLASS");   

    for(var i=0; i < deleteButtonArray.length ; ++i){
            this.parentNode.remove();
    }
}


function addTask(){
    listITEMS.classList.remove('hidden');
    const ITEM = createListElement(inputTXT.value);
    document.getElementsByClassName("items")[0].appendChild(ITEM);
    inputTXT.value = '';    //Resets user input string
}



submitBUTT.addEventListener("click", addTask);
```